# How can I add class to an element after it has loaded asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, ajax, addclass

My problem is when the element is loaded by AJAX and it's appended in the DOM during the success callback the addClass method executes too soon and the transitions are not displayed.

```
$.ajax({
    url : contentURL,
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "html",
    success : function(response){
        $content.append(response);
        $activeSection = $('#'+href);   // appended element
        $activeSection.addClass("open"); // class is added before appending
    }
});
```

Problem without ajax: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gel00/1ond41d4/3/)

Comment: Ajax, in all forms and shapes, have callbacks. This is where you're inserting the element into the DOM, and this is where you'll add the class.

Comment: have you tried try/catch/finally : 
try{dom.insert()}finally{dom.child.addClass()}

Comment: You need to include your code.

Comment: There is a "complete" callback, that suppose to run after the "success" callback, but it adds class before the appending somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manipulating the DOM is really resource intensive. While a new element is under construction it was given it's class attribute. My solution is preparing a wrapper element before manipulating the DOM, and modifying the class attribute only on the wrapper. Right after the new element has been created I have inserted a new empty wrapper for further content loading.

[my solution](https://jsfiddle.net/gel00/s0yem16s/)

```
function addClass(el, classN) {
  var hasClass = el.className.search(classN)+1;
  if (hasClass) {
      return true
  } else {
      el.className += el.className ? " "+classN : classN;
  }
}
function removeClass(el, classN) {
  var re = new RegExp("\\s*"+classN, "ig");
    el.className = el.className.replace(re, "");
    if (el.className.length === 0) {
        el.removeAttribute("class");
    }
}
function dropping (el, classN, duration){
    addClass(el, classN);
  setTimeout(function(){
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    state2 = null;
  }, duration);
}
function opening(e) {
    if (!open) {
    open = true;
    addClass(w1, "open");
    addClass(w2, "open");
    addClass(state0, "open");
    state1 = state0;
    state0 = conClear.cloneNode(true);
    w3.appendChild(state0);
  }
}
function closing(e) {
    if (open) {
    open = false;
    removeClass(w1, "open");
    removeClass(w2, "open");
    dropping(state1, "drop", 1000);
    state2 = state1;
    state1 = null;
  }
}
function paging(e){
    if (open) {
    dropping(state1, "drop", 1000);
    state2 = state1;
    addClass(state0, "open");
    state1 = state0;
    state0 = conClear.cloneNode(true);
    w3.appendChild(state0);
  }
}
var open = false;
var bO = document.getElementById("open");
var bC = document.getElementById("close");
var bP = document.getElementById("page");

var w1 = document.getElementById("wrapper1");
var w2 = document.getElementById("wrapper2");
var w3 = document.getElementById("wrapper3");
var con = w3.getElementsByClassName("content").item(0);
var state0 = con;
var state1 = null;
var state2 = null;
var conClear = con.cloneNode(true);

bO.addEventListener("click", opening, false);
bC.addEventListener("click", closing, false);
bP.addEventListener("click", paging, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use some like:

```
  setInterval(function(){
    if($('#elementId').html() != null) {
      $('#elementId').addClass('.class');
      return;
    }
    console.log('Working...');
    }, 1000);
```

This is run antil the element exist and class has been adedded. (sorry for bad english)

Comment: Nice cheat. Unfortunately it's not an option.

Comment: Same result as before.

Comment: But you added the block outside the ajax block?

Answer (score 0):

You should try sync ajax call
i.e. async: false

refer following link for more detail
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I hope there is a less radical solution.